# Помогите с версткой на Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Добрый день. Подскажите, как сверстать такой дизайн, с использованием bootstrap.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что весь контент расположен в блоке container? а справа полоски черные уходят до края экрана. У меня пока одна мысль - разместить полоски с позиционированием absolute, внутри контейнера с позиционирование relative, совместив тем самым их с полосами контента. Но это я думаю приведет к неразберихе, в зависимости от размера экрана, придется сильно много корректировать.
Есть решение легче?

Сейчас сделано так:

```
    <div class="container-fluid uslugi">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title">Мы <span>доставляем</span></h2>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u001">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>350</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Песок</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u002">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>700</span><br>руб/тонна </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name">Щебень<br>известняковый</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u003">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>1300</span><br>руб/тонна </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name">Щебень<br>гравийный</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u004">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>2000</span><br>руб/тонна </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name">Щебень<br>гранитный</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u005">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>1000</span><br>руб/тонна </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name">Асфальтная<br>крошка</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u006">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>400</span><br>руб/тонна </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name">Битый<br>кирпич</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u007">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>700</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Навоз</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u008">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>800</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Перегной</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u009">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>800</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Чернозем</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u010">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>1000</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Торф</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row uslugi_line u011">
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_img"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 uslugi_price">от<br><span>300</span><br>руб/м </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 uslugi_name one_line">Грунт</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю тут лучше ставить container внутри каждой полоски, а контейнер полосок при этом так - `position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: половина_ширины`

Comment: То есть полоски row внутри container-fluid? А внутри row div class="container?" Добавил так как сейчас сделано в вопрос.

Comment: Можно использовать свои настройки в bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
смотри в Container sizes, Grid system, Media queries breakpoints

Comment: Причем тут свои настройки?